# Typescript throws error on index type although const object and type contains it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I must admit that I am missing some knowledge regarding TypeScript, but I can't wrap my head around the following problem. Hope someone can enlighten me on this.

I have a functional component that serves to display the correct component depending on its props. It looks something like this:

```
type PossibleProps =
  {identification: {
      ident: 'ident_1',
      type: 'type_1'
  }} |
  {identification: {
      ident: 'ident_2',
      type: 'type_2'
  }} |
  {identification: {
      ident: 'ident_2',
      type: 'type_3'
  }};

const getComponent:React.FC<PossibleProps> = (props) => {
    const componentArray = {
        ident_1: {
            type_1: "ComponentOne",
        },
        ident_2: {
            type_2: "ComponentTwo",
            type_3: "ComponentThree",
        },
    } as const;

    const Component = componentArray?.[props.identification.ident]?.[props.identification.type] || "ErrorUi";
    return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

*The Component Name Strings are just to keep the error message readable. On the real component its imported components of course.*

Im my mind this should work: the PossibleProps only contain objects that are included in the componentArray, and even if something won't be included, the ErrorUi would serve the spot.

Nevertheless I get following Error Message from Typescript:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"type_1" | "type_2" | "type_3"' can't be used to index type '{ readonly type_1: "ComponentOne"; } | { readonly type_2: "ComponentTwo"; readonly type_3: "ComponentThree"; }'.
  Property 'type_1' does not exist on type '{ readonly type_1: "ComponentOne"; } | { readonly type_2: "ComponentTwo"; readonly type_3: "ComponentThree"; }'.ts(7053)
```

I would really appreciate somebody helping me find out why typescript is complaining here.

Thanks a lot!

As mentioned my experience regarding Typescript is limited.

I tested a few things tho and found a working way:

```
    const componentArray = {
        ident_1: {
            type_1: "ComponentOne",
            type_2: "ErrorUi",
            type_3: "ErrorUi",
        },
        ident_2: {
            type_1: "ErrorUi",
            type_2: "ComponentTwo",
            type_3: "ComponentThree",
        },
    } as const;
```

With the real component and about 50 types split over about 30 idents (with more to come) this gets pretty massive and hard to read of course, so I would really appreciate not having to fall back to this implementation.

**Edit**: I found a working solution. It's not my favorite but it ticks all boxes for now.

I am keeping a separate Object allTypes that includes all possible types with the ErrorUi assigned to it. I then add these default types to all ident objects satisfying typescript and keeping my object human-readable:

```
    const allTypes = {
        type_1: "ErrorUi",
        type_2: "ErrorUi",
        type_3: "ErrorUi",
    } as const;

    const componentArray = {
        ident_1: {
            ... allTypes,
            type_1: "ComponentOne",
        },
        ident_2: {
            ... allTypes,
            type_2: "ComponentTwo",
            type_3: "ComponentThree",
        },
    } as const;
```

If someone knows a better way I would still appreciate your contribution :)

Comment: Does this question depend on React? If so you might want to tag it as such; if not you might want to remove the example code's dependency on it so that it can be a [mre] involving only TypeScript

Comment: I suspect you should rather use something like `type PossibleProps = {identification: {ident: 'ident_1'; type: 'type_1'} | {ident: 'ident_2'; type: 'type_2' | 'type_3' }};`

Comment: Unfortunatly this won't be possible. This is a minimal example. On the real code, each PossibleProps option resembles the props of a distinct component that needs different props. The real PossibleProps Type is therefore much bigger and imports a bunch of other types from these components.

Answer (score 0):

Try another approach where you request the data through props, and then return the correct component.

Example:

```
interface Props {
  variant: “type1” | “type2”
}

const MyComponent = ({variant}: Props => {
  if (variant === “type1”) {
    return <WhateverNeeded />
  }
   …code

}
```

I believe your issue is that you’re trying to compare objects, which may not work as you might expect. Object comparison is not as strict as comparing primitives, the rules around it can be too vague. One easy easy solution could also be to stringify your objects therefore ‘faking’ strict types. You want to avoid this because you lose type safety. Converting your data into strings used as keys to dereference your data somewhat defeats the purpose of TypeScript.

Funny, I think your issue could also be that you haven’t properly defined the types for your keys. Try casting your union type to a string using “as string” directly after use, similar to your “as const”

May not have overlap, in which case try “as unknown as string”

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I tried your solution with ident components that have if clauses to return the correct component. Unfortunately on my current setup this adds a lot of code and makes the file(s) hard to read (something I would like to avoid). Also using ident components causes me to have to write distinct propTypes for each ident, forcing a lot more types to be written. I would really like to solve this problem using object ident. There has to be a way in typescript to make nested objects possible.